# Possible bug in ifort

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

While trying to use a type for blockdiagonal matrices in Fortran code,
I stumbled over a surprising bug in the following piece of code using the following compilers:

```
GNU Fortran (SUSE Linux) 7.4.0
ifort (IFORT) 18.0.5 20180823
ifort (IFORT) 16.0.1 20151021
```

If I compile

```
gfortran -Wall -Werror --debug ifort_bug.f && valgrind ./a.out
```

I have no errors reported from valgrind.

If I compile

```
ifort -warn all,error -debug -stacktrace ifort_bug.f && valgrind ./a.out
```

I get a segmentation fault for ifort_18 in my code and "only" memory leaks for ifort_16.

Is this a bug in the intel compilers, or does gfortran silently fix my bad code?

```
      module blockdiagonal_matrices
        implicit none
        private
        public :: t_blockdiagonal, new, delete,
     &    blocksizes, operator(.mult.), mult
        save

        integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)

        type :: t_blockdiagonal
          real(dp), allocatable :: block(:, :)
        end type

        interface new
          module procedure block_new
        end interface

        interface delete
          module procedure block_delete
        end interface

        interface operator (.mult.)
          module procedure mult_blocks
        end interface

      contains

        subroutine block_new(blocks, blocksizes)
          type(t_blockdiagonal), intent(out) :: blocks(:)
          integer, intent(in) :: blocksizes(:)
          integer :: i, L

          do i = 1, size(blocks)
            L = blocksizes(i)
            allocate(blocks(i)%block(L, L))
          end do
        end subroutine

        subroutine block_delete(blocks)
          type(t_blockdiagonal) :: blocks(:)
          integer :: i

          do i = 1, size(blocks)
            deallocate(blocks(i)%block)
          end do
        end subroutine

        function blocksizes(A) result(res)
          type(t_blockdiagonal), intent(in) :: A(:)
          integer :: res(size(A))

          integer :: i
          res = [(size(A(i)%block, 1), i = 1, size(A))]
        end function

        function mult_blocks(A, B) result(C)
          type(t_blockdiagonal), intent(in) :: A(:), B(:)
          type(t_blockdiagonal) :: C(size(A))

          integer :: i

          call new(C, blocksizes=blocksizes(A))
          do i = 1, size(A)
            C(i)%block = matmul(A(i)%block, B(i)%block)
          end do
        end function

        subroutine mult(A, B, C)
          type(t_blockdiagonal), intent(in) :: A(:), B(:)
          type(t_blockdiagonal) :: C(:)

          integer :: i

          do i = 1, size(A)
            C(i)%block = matmul(A(i)%block, B(i)%block)
          end do
        end subroutine
      end module blockdiagonal_matrices

      program time_blockdiagonal
        use blockdiagonal_matrices
        integer, parameter :: n_blocks = 2, L_block = 10**2
        type(t_blockdiagonal) :: A(n_blocks), B(n_blocks), C(n_blocks)
        integer :: i
        integer :: start, finish, rate

        call system_clock(count_rate=rate)
        call new(A, blocksizes=[(L_block, i = 1, n_blocks)])
        call new(B, blocksizes=[(L_block, i = 1, n_blocks)])
        call new(C, blocksizes=[(L_block, i = 1, n_blocks)])

        do i = 1, n_blocks
          call random_number(A(i)%block)
          call random_number(B(i)%block)
        end do


        call system_clock(start)
        C = A .mult. B
        call system_clock(finish)
        write(6,*) 'Elapsed Time in seconds:',
     &    dble(finish - start) / dble(rate)

        call system_clock(start)
        call mult(A, B, C)
        call system_clock(finish)
        write(6,*) 'Elapsed Time in seconds:',
     &    dble(finish - start) / dble(rate)

        call delete(A)
        call delete(B)
        call delete(C)


      end program time_blockdiagonal
```

The ifort_18 segmentation fault is:

```
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
a.out              00000000004134BD  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libpthread-2.26.s  00007FF720EB6300  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              000000000040ABB8  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              000000000040B029  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000407113  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000402B4E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.26.so       00007FF720B0AF8A  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000402A6A  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

When I went into it with `gdb` it turned out, that the segfault is raised upon returning from function `mult_blocks`.

```
blockdiagonal_matrices::mult_blocks (c=..., a=..., b=...) at ifort_bug.f:63
63            do i = 1, size(A)
(gdb) s
64              C(i)%block = matmul(A(i)%block, B(i)%block)
(gdb) s
s
s
65            end do
(gdb) s
64              C(i)%block = matmul(A(i)%block, B(i)%block)
(gdb) s
65            end do
(gdb) s
66          end function
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040abc4 in do_deallocate_all ()
(gdb) q
A debugging session is active.
```

Even with this information I cannot find a bug in my code.

## EDIT

I found a fix, although I don't understand why it works.

### Compilation fix

If I use `-heap-arrays` for compilation it works. So at first glance it seems to run into a Stackoverflow. If I do `ulimit -s unlimited` it **does not** solve the problem though.

### Code fix

If I explicitly allocate in the code it solves the issue.

```
        subroutine new(blocks, blocksizes)
          type(t_blockdiagonal), allocatable, intent(out) :: blocks(:)
          integer, intent(in) :: blocksizes(:)
          integer :: i, L

          allocate(blocks(size(blocksizes)))
          do i = 1, size(blocks)
            L = blocksizes(i)
            allocate(blocks(i)%block(L, L))
          end do
        end subroutine

        subroutine delete(blocks)
          type(t_blockdiagonal), allocatable :: blocks(:)
          integer :: i

          do i = 1, size(blocks)
            deallocate(blocks(i)%block)
          end do
          deallocate(blocks)
        end subroutine

        function mult_blocks(A, B) result(C)
          type(t_blockdiagonal), intent(in) :: A(:), B(:)
          type(t_blockdiagonal), allocatable :: C(:)

          integer :: i

          call new(C, blocksizes=blocksizes(A))
          do i = 1, size(A)
            C(i)%block = matmul(A(i)%block, B(i)%block)
          end do
        end function
```

This way of writing is IMHO actually better than before and not a "dirty hack". 
It is not anymore possible to call `new` with a differing size of `blocksize` and `blocks`.

### Open question

Speaking C the `type(t_blockdiagonal) :: blocks(n)` 
Should be a `float** blocks[n]` so just a vector of pointers to pointers. 
The allocation of the actual blocks happened also in the first version on the heap. Hence I don't get the Stackoverflow for a vector that contains ca. 10 pointers.

Comment: What kind of segmentation fault? Compiler's or your code's? Compiler's segfaults are obviously always compiler bugs. Please show the complete output/error message.

Comment: What happens if you turn on run time checks, for instance -fcheck=alll with gfortran?

Comment: @IanBush Neither gfortran nor ifort showed boundary violations. And to repeat what I said in the question: For gfortran I have no errors reported from valgrind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Intel® Fortran Compiler - Increased stack usage of 8.0 or higher compilers causes segmentation fault (via archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20151019022503/https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-fortran-compiler-increased-stack-usage-of-80-or-higher-compilers-causes-segmentation-fault)

According to this article, `ulimit -s unlimited` does not mean that the stack will be literally "unlimited":

> The size of "unlimited" varies by Linux configuration, so you may need to specify a larger, specific number to ulimit (for example, 999999999). On Linux also note that many 32bit Linux distributions ship with a pthread static library (libpthread.a) that at runtime will fix the stacksize to 2093056 bytes regardless of the ulimit setting.

It is most likely that you do indeed have a stack overflow, given that `-heap-arrays` solves the issue.